# Tiff picture into canvas and convert into png

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, tiff

I have a tif-image file as base64 string and i want to convert it into png/jpeg. Is there any easy way to do this?

My idea would be to put the .tif-image into a new canvas and convert this canvas into a png-file. Is this a possible way to do so?

Comment: If your browser doesn't support tiff (like most browsers) then there is no other way to draw it on a canvas than parsing it yourself and convert it manually to a format the browser supports; that is, the canvas is useless. Now, tiff is a container and can contain a whole lot of different things in many various formats (not only images oO). This writting yourself a parser may not be easy.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. Do you thing this will help me? https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js

Comment: I guess yes, if you're ok with a 1.5MB lib, certainly better than having to write it yourself. But personnally, I'd double check why I get a tiff image in the first place, for instance, if it's coming from a server, I'd certainly make the  conversion server-side.

Comment: yes but i have no idea how to convert the tif server-side.

Comment: There are many ways, a free one: https://imagemagick.org

Comment: thanks for your help. the problem is that i cant make any changes on server-side. now i am trying to implement the lib. i am still struggling with it...

Comment: do you have any experiences with this library or in general with integration such libs?